# Configuring and testing Stripe Accounts Create for Stripe custom

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am trying to configure stripe.accounts.create({}) for Stripe custom. My goal here is to create everything in one form so the user fulfills all of the information requirements for their stripe account to transact after the form is compete. When testing the current code using the credit card number Stripe recommended, I am getting the error that is displayed after the following code block. I am wondering if there is a tokenization process that I am missing that isn't referenced in the stripe create account docs. This is my current post method

```
var knex = require("../models/knex"),
    express = require('express'),
    middleware = require("../middleware/index"),
    stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_VALUEOFMYTESTKEY"),
    router = express.Router({mergeParams:true});
    router.post("/formuser",function(req,res){
    console.log(req.user[0].user_id);
    knex("users.user").select("*").where("user_id",req.user[0].user_id)
    .then((user) => {
      var today = new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString();
      var accountType = String(req.body.accountType).toLowerCase();
      var checkIfCard = accountType=="card";
      console.log(req.body.accountType,checkIfCard,String(req.body.cardNumber));
      var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || 
               req.connection.remoteAddress || 
               req.socket.remoteAddress ||
               req.connection.socket.remoteAddress; 

      console.log(ip);
      if(!checkIfCard){
          stripe.accounts.create({
        email: user.email,
        country: "US",
        type: "custom",
        //Required fields for Custom via... https://stripe.com/docs/connect/required-verification-information
        metadata: {
        "external_account": {
          "object": "bank_account", 
          "exp_month": req.body.cardExpirationMonth,
          "exp_year":  req.body.cardExpirationYear,// : null,
          "number":  req.body.bankNumber,// : null,

        },                        //external account info... https://stripe.com/docs/api#account_create_bank_account
        "city": req.body.city,
        "legal_entity.adress.line1": req.body.streetAddress,
        "legal_entity.address.postal_code": req.body.zipCode,
        "legal_entity.address.state": req.body.state,
        "legal_entity.dob.day": req.body.birthDay,
        "legal_entity.dob.month": req.body.birthMonth,
        "legal_entity.dob.year": req.body.birthYear,
        "legal_entity.first_name": req.body.firstName,
        "legal_entity.last_name": req.body.lastName,
        "legal_entity.ssn_last_4": req.body.ssn_last_4,
        "tos_acceptance.date": today,
        "tos_acceptance.ip": ip,
        }

      }).then((acct) => {
        res.redirect("/");
      })
    .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
      } else {
          stripe.accounts.create({
        email: user.email,
        country: "US",
        type: "custom",
        //Required fields for Custom via... https://stripe.com/docs/connect/required-verification-information
        metadata: {
        "external_account": {
          "object": "card", //bank account or cc or dc...
          "card": req.body.cardNumber.toString(),
          "cvc" : req.body.cvc.toString(),
          "currency" : "usd",// : null

        },                        //external account info... https://stripe.com/docs/api#account_create_bank_account
        "city": req.body.city,
        "legal_entity.adress.line1": req.body.streetAddress,
        "legal_entity.address.postal_code": req.body.zipCode,
        "legal_entity.address.state": req.body.state,
        "legal_entity.dob.day": req.body.birthDay,
        "legal_entity.dob.month": req.body.birthMonth,
        "legal_entity.dob.year": req.body.birthYear,
        "legal_entity.first_name": req.body.firstName,
        "legal_entity.last_name": req.body.lastName,
        "legal_entity.ssn_last_4": req.body.ssn_last_4,
        "tos_acceptance.date": today,
        "tos_acceptance.ip": ip,
        }

      }).then((acct) => {
        res.redirect("/");
      })
    .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
      }});
});
```

When I enter in the credit card information that Stripe recommends to test, I get the following error

```
   { [Error: Invalid val: {"object"=>"card", "card"=>"4242 4242 4242 4242", "cvc"=>"111", "currency"=>"usd"} must be a string under 500 characters]
  type: 'StripeInvalidRequestError',
  stack: 'Error: Invalid val: {"object"=>"card", "card"=>"4242 4242 4242 4242", "cvc"=>"111", "currency"=>"usd"} must be a string under 500 character
```

when I expected a user to be created.

EDIT: I removed some of the knex database code in this post to shorten it's length as it is not relevant to the current error. The current error is specifically from Stripe's promise.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to pass bank account details in `external_account` but also passing card data at the same time. This is unlikely to be what you want.

On top of this, you should not be passing this information server-side at all as it's sensitive. Instead, you should be creating a token client-side. For card data, you would use [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/elements) and for bank account data you would build your own form and tokenize with [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js#collecting-bank-account-details). Once this is done, you get a card token `tok_123` or a bank account token `btok_123` and can then use this server-side in the `external_account` parameter.

Then, you should also pass the data as nested hashes. This means that you would not pass `"legal_entity.adress.line1"` but instead `legal_entity[address][line1]`. Your code should instead look something like this:

```
stripe.accounts.create( 
{
  type: 'custom',
  country: 'US',
  legal_entity : {
    first_name : 'john',
    last_name : 'doe',
    type : 'individual',
    address: {
      line1: 'line1',
      city: 'city',
      state: 'state',
      postal_code: '90210',
      country: 'US'
    } 
  },
  external_account: 'tok_visa_debit',
}).then((acct) => {
  console.log('account: ', JSON.stringify(acct));
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log(e);
});
```